# How to efficiently use wget with github archive

Tags: unix, github, wget

Currently I am using `wget` to download source code from github as an archive.

Example:

`wget -N https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.8.0.tar.gz`

There are many such commands in shell script.
Only problem is each time the script executes a fresh copy of `.tar.gz` file is downloaded even the same copy already exists. `wget -N` fails with message `Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.`

How to avoid re-downloading of same file?

Comment: Check option `-c` https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9557/53084

Comment: check also this answer is one using `curl -z` https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928671/1135424, problem is that the GitHub don't sent any of does headers